# How to change/spoof ProcessorID / CPU ID

Tags: cpuid

Is there a way to change/spoof WMIC output for some time using a program, I am not using vm and therefor I want a way to change spoof cpuid for limited time

Comment: Who's reading the data? Using which method? You could just recompile the kernel and return whatever you want?